# why does this simple program break with values over 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and have this problem to continuously take user input, validate whether it's an integer and print out the maximum and minimum values at the end. The program breaks when mixing values below 10 with values above 10. Please help me understand why.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : 
        break
    try :
        int(num)
        if smallest is None and largest is None :
            smallest = largest = num
        if num < smallest :
            smallest = num
            print(num)
        if num > largest :
            largest = num
            print(num)
    except :
        print("Invalid input")
print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Comment: what exactly is the above and below 10, `num` or `smallest` or `largest`? (first thought: u should use `elif` instead of `if`..)

Comment: You should probably store the return value of `int(num)` somewhere and make more meaningful comparisons using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you check whether `num` can be cast to an `int` (using the try-except block), you never actually store the result of the casting in a variable. `int(num)` only returns the integer value of `num`; to actually change `num` to an `int`, use `num = int(num)`. What happens in your program is that you compare strings instead of numbers, leading to unexpected behavior.